# PropertyNotFoundException in EL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

Can some one help me with the exception I have.

in servlet i send list of countries to jsp

```
request.setAttribute("countries", allCountryList);
```

and in jsp i want to display them in dropdown list , i use `foreach` to fill the ddl with values

```
 <c:forEach var="country" items="${requestScope.countries}" >
            <option value="${country.countryNo}">${country.countryName}</option>
  </c:forEach>
```

Strange exception says that countryName is not exist even it is exist

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'countryName' not found on type ps.iugaza.onlineinfosys.entities.Country
```

and here is country class

```
public class Country {
private String countryName;
private int countryNo;
public String getCoutnryName() {
    return countryName;
}     
public int getCountryNo() {
    return countryNo;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited:

Have you built the project again? Maybe you add the name attribute and you havent compiled the project again.

The getter should be getCountryName instead of getCoutnryName

Comment: It doesn't wrok, that's becouse I should specify the scope.

Comment: I make clean and build, but the same:(

Comment: @Alaa Could you post your getter method?

Comment: @Alaa the getter should be getCountryName instead of getCoutnryName

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanx

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo, `getCoutnryName()` should be `getCountryName()`.

A bit decent IDE can autogenerate getters/setters based on fields. I'd suggest to make use of its powers.

Comment: I'll keep in mind than next time, many thanx for advices and help